# In Python, how to compute array of values in a vectorized manner and not inside a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The question is:

Write and test a Python script which accepts a list of up to 5 values for the exponent n from input and plots the curves of **y = 1/(x^n + 1)** on the same graph. The program should create a NumPy arrays for x, and y_0, y_1, ... up to y_4 values. The x coordinate array should consist of 201 evenly spaced values between -10 and 10 (including -10 and 10). **You should compute the y values by performing vectorized operations on x (do NOT compute y values one at a time in a loop)**. Plot y_0 versus x on a graph in blue and plot y_1 (and so forth) versus x on the same graph in red, green, cyan, and magenta. You should put a title on your plot along the axis labels for the x and y axis and a grid. When you are ready, remember to use the show() function

The show() command without arguments will pause the code execution. Your program should print a message to the screen reminding users to close the plot window for the program to proceed. Once the user closes the figure, your program should loop back and allow the user to enter another sequence of values for n. The program should accept any floating point values for n and terminate if 'q' is entered as the first value. If 'q' is entered as the second, third, fourth or fifth value, the program should produce a plot with only those values (e.g. if you enter 2, 4, 6, q, then the program should produce a plot with only three curves in blue, red, and green and then return for more input). For all other input the program should print a message indicating that there was an issue and ask the user to enter a value for n again. (Hint: you can *try* before attempting to convert the input string to a float with an *except* clause for a *ValueError* in case the float conversion doesn't work.) Your program should NOT terminate on bad input. Run your program for n=2, 4, 8, 'fred', 16, 32, (which should produce a graph) and then n=2, 4, 9, and ,q, (which should produce another graph... and possible a run-time warning about dividing by 0...), and then 'q' to terminate.

The output should look something like what follows. Note that the *title*, *xlabel*, and *ylabel* pyplot commands accept strings that can use the format method to incorporate variables into the string.

```
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>2
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>4
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>8
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>fred
That's not a number!!!
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>16
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>32
Close plot window to continue...
```

[Image for the above input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvBo.jpg)

```
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>2
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>4
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>9
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>q
Warning (from warnings module):
 File "F:/ENTS 656 Lab/HW4/H4_1.py", line 14
y3 = 1/((x**n_list[1])+1)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
Close plot window to continue...
```

[Image for above output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLl1A.jpg)

```
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>q
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import sys
while True:
    try:
        n_list = []
        for i in range(5):
            exponent = input('Enter exponent n (q to quit)>')
            n_list.insert(i,float(exponent))
    except ValueError:
        if exponent == 'q' and i == 0:
            sys.exit()
        elif exponent == 'q' and i != 0:
            break
        else:
            print('That\'s not a number!!!')
            for j in range(i,5):
                exponent = input('Enter exponent n (q to quit)>')
                n_list.insert(j,float(exponent))
    finally:
        if exponent == 'q' and i == 0:
            sys.exit()
        print(n_list)
        x = np.linspace(-10,10,num=201)
        y1 = 1/((x**n_list[0])+1)
        y2 = 1/((x**n_list[1])+1)
        y3 = 1/((x**n_list[2])+1)
        y4 = 1/((x**n_list[3])+1)
        y5 = 1/((x**n_list[4])+1)
        mplt.plot(x,y1,'b-')
        mplt.plot(x,y2,'r-')
        mplt.plot(x,y3,'g-')
        mplt.plot(x,y4,'c-')
        mplt.plot(x,y5,'m-')
        mplt.title('$1/(x^n+1)$, n={}'.format(n_list))
        mplt.xlabel('x')
        mplt.ylabel('f(x)')
        mplt.grid(True)
        print('Close plot window to continue...')
        mplt.show()
```

My output reads:

```
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>2
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>4
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>8
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>fred
That's not a number!!!
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>16
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>32
```

And, when I give my output as:

```
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>2
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>4
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>9
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>q
That's not a number
Enter exponent n (q to quit)>
```

The problem is, the program doesn't quit after q is entered after the first input. Can someone please explain the logic for the second part when 2, 4, 9, q is entered? and also is there another way i can compute the y values?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: in your code, you have the line `if exponent == 'q' and i == 0:`. Why the `i == 0` statement?

Comment: The program should exit only when the first input is q, so the i == 0 checks whether it is the entered q is the first or not.

Comment: So how would you look for a case where the exponent is `'q'` but it's not the first value entered?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't have the problem that you mention but it fails creating the plots for `i==3` and `i==4` in the second case because there are no such list elements.

I've tried around and because I like a clear programming style with functions I created a small script that should fulfill your needs. (Initially I tried your solution but I always stumbled upon some error and finally just tried to implement it myself). I hope the comments can convey why I did something like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import sys

def getinput():
    n_list = []
    # Use a while loop instead of a for loop
    while len(n_list) < 5:

        # Get some number
        exponent = input('Enter exponent n (q to quit)>')

        # This will fail with a ValueError if it cannot be converted to float
        try:
            n_list.append(float(exponent))

        # Never use bare except statements!
        except ValueError:
            if exponent == 'q':
                if n_list:
                    # empty lists evaluate to False so we have some elements
                    # Returning them breaks the loop and exits the function
                    return n_list
                else:
                    # We had no elements in the list so just exit
                    sys.exit()
            # It wasn't q so it was a bad input
            else:
                print('That is not a number!!!')
    return n_list

def plotthem(n_list):
    x = np.linspace(-10,10,num=201)
    style = ['b-', 'r-', 'g-', 'c-','m-']
    # Only plot as many lines as there are objects in the list (and use the appropriate style)
    for i in range(len(n_list)):
        mplt.plot(x, 1/((x**n_list[i])+1), style[i])
    mplt.title('$1/(x^n+1)$, n={}'.format(n_list))
    mplt.xlabel('x')
    mplt.ylabel('f(x)')
    mplt.grid(True)
    print('Close plot window to continue...')
    mplt.show()

# If started as script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        plotthem(getinput())
```

---

To calculate the resulting functions in a completly vectorized solution you could replace them by:

```
# Completly vectorized solution - result has shape (len(n_list), 201)
y =  1/((x[None,:]**np.array(n_list)[:,None])+1)
for i in range(len(n_list)):
    # Now change this to plotting the i-th row of y
    mplt.plot(x, y[i], style[i])
```

Comment: MSeifert, I really must appreciate your coding style, but I can see you have indirectly computed the y values inside a loop here for i in range(len(n_list)): mplt.plot(x, 1/((x**n_list[i])+1), style[i]) The question specifically says You should compute the y values by performing vectorized operations on x (do NOT compute y values one at a time in a loop). So, considering this, how do we do it?

Comment: @Cute_Parrot - `1/((x**n_list[i])+1)` is still a vectorized operation. The assignment says you shouldn't loop over `x` but you *are* allowed to loop over `n_list` :)

Comment: @Cute_Parrot - Eveen though I agree with morningsun and think that's vectorized enough: I included a completly vectorized solution at the end of the answer, just insert this instead of the former loop.

Comment: @MSeifert - I kinda get what is going on and appreciate the effort and the answer in `y =  1/((x[None,:]**np.array(n_list)[:,None])+1)` but, is it possible to explain what exactly is going on, or what does it do?